# If $f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $x_0$, what conditions on $f$ guarantee the differentiability of $g$ at $x_0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Justify: If $f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $x_0$, what conditions on $f$ guarantee the differentiability of $g$ at $x_0$?

I tried coming up with an example, like $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=|x|$. $g$ is not differentiable at $x_0=0$, but $f$ is and $f\cdot g$ is differentiable at $x_0=0$. Now, let $f(x)=g(x)=|x|$. Neither functions are differentiable at $x_0$, but $f\cdot g$ is. So, can I conclude $f$ just has to be continuous at $x_0=0$? Any hint, please?

Edit: $f\cdot g=f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: $f$ does not need to be continuous if $fg$ is differentiable: Take $g \equiv 0$.

Comment: What if $g(x) \neq 0$? Does it suffice to have $f$ continuous? Do I have to break it down into cases?

Comment: No, $f \equiv 1$, $g(x) = 1 + |x|$.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Necessary or sufficient conditions on $f$? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: @Keba, that's the statement of the exercise. I didn't make it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices for $f$ to be differentiable and $f(x_0) \ne 0$. Let $h(x)=f(x) g(x)$. THen
$$g'(x) = \left(\frac {h(x)} {f(x)}\right)'
= \frac {h'(x) f(x) - f'(x) h(x)} {f^2(x)}$$

On the other hand, this doesn't have to hold when $f(x)=0$. One example is $f(x) \equiv 0$ and $g(x) = any\ function$.

Comment: $f\cdot g = f(x)g(x)$. I thought this was a standard notation for the product of two functions. Sorry if it is not.

Comment: @MauricioMendes, then it's even simper.